Is this non-mathematical interpretation of cause-specific vs subdistribution hazards sensible?
I am interested in estimating the risk of readmissions accounting for the competing risk of death. I would like to explain both types of models to people with a basic understanding of statistics.

Cause-specific HRs describe the association between the exposure and event of interest directly because competing events are censored.

However, cause-specific HRs may overestimate risk in the real-world where the competing event is a possible outcome.

Compared to cause-specific approaches, the subdistribution models allows outcomes to be predicted under the more realistic condition where the event of interest and competing event are both allowed to happen.

However, subdistribution HRs are more difficult to interpret from an etiologic standpoint because individuals who have died (and are no longer at risk of the event) are retained in the denominator, mixing the two outcomes.


HRs = Hazard Ratios
ps. my understanding of these topics comes partly from this paper:
Schuster NA, Hoogendijk EO, Kok AAL, Twisk JWR, Heymans MW. Ignoring competing events in the analysis of survival data may lead to biased results: a nonmathematical illustration of competing risk analysis. J Clin Epidemiol. 2020 Jun;122:42-48. doi: 10.1016/j.jclinepi.2020.03.004. Epub 2020 Mar 9. PMID: 32165133.


cause-specific HRs may overestimate risk in the real-world where the competing event is a possible outcome

It depends on what you mean by "cause-specific" and what you mean by "risk."
I don't see a need to restrict the phrase "cause-specific" to models in which you censor the time to an event of interest at the time of the competing event. Multi-state survival models can handle both "causes" jointly in a way that provides correct estimates, for either event type, of the hazards associated with predictor variables and the probability of the event over time, $p(t)$. The R competing risks vignette explains this nicely in Section 3.1, for a model that treats plasma cell malignancy (PCM) and death as competing events:

The same Cox model coefficients can also be obtained by fitting separate models for the PCM and death endpoint, censoring cases that fail due to the other cause. Hazards can be computed one at a time. When computing $p(t)$, on the other hand, all the rates must be considered at once, it is necessary to use the joint fit cfit1 above.

Even with a restricted interpretation of "cause-specific" to simple censoring at the time of the competing event, you still get the correct associations of predictor variables with the hazard of an event. If by "risk" you mean the instantaneous risk, the "hazard" of an event at a particular time as a function of predictor variables, then there is no problem.
If you instead take "risk" to be the probability of having experienced a particular event type over time, $p(t)$, you also get the correct "risk" in that sense from a multi-state Cox model (given that model assumptions are met). You will not overestimate the probability of either event, as "the event of interest and competing event are both allowed to happen" in a multi-state Cox model.
After several years working on survival analysis, I still struggle with a simple heuristic explanation of subdistribution hazards. Nevertheless, Fine-Gray subdistribution hazard models do have one advantage, explained in Section 4 of the competing-risks vignette:

The primary strength of the Fine-Gray model with respect to the Cox model approach is that if lifetime risk is a primary question, then the model has given us a simple and digestible answer to that question: "females have a 1.2 fold higher lifetime risk of PCM, after adjustment for age and serum m-spike".

